# linqpad hide specific column or restrict row to single line

Tags: c#, linq, linqpad

`ATable.Dump()` in linqpad returns the whole ATable.
However, `ATable.Single().MassiveColumn` contains too much data and it fills up the whole results page.

Is there a way to either:

1. Write this more concisely `ATable.Select(t=> new {col1 = t.column1, col2 = t.column2, ..., coln = t.columnn})` and omit `MassiveColumn`. (The table has about 20 columns and I want to select everything except `MassiveColumn`)
2. Hide `MassiveColumn` from being dumped.

Or is there any other options to restrict the dump to only allow one line per row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an option to limit column widths in Edit | Preferences | Advanced (last option in list).

Would that help?

Answer (score 1):

This should also work:

```cs
ATable.Dump(exclude:"MassiveColumn");
```

If you want to exclude more columns, you can do this

```cs
ATable.Dump(exclude:"MassiveColumn1,MassiveColumn2");
```